# Downloading PDF file on my test for further upload

Tags: pdf, testing, download, automated-tests, testcafe

In my test, I need to click on a "Download Button" which triggers an HTTP request that automatically downloads the PDF file to my Download directory, and later on, I need to upload the same PDF file somewhere else in my test.

So here is the problem, since I don't know the download directory of the computer which will actually run the test I need to control the path to which the download saves the file, how can I do that with testcafe?

Here are some attempts to use HTTP Request Hook and later on save the file, but when trying to open the PDF file the data is corrupted

```
 .click(await new Selector('[class="fi font-download_alt "]'))
    const requests = logger.requests.length;

    const buf = logger.requests[requests-1].response.body;


   console.log(decoder.write(cent));
    console.log(buf.toJSON());
   console.log(buf.toString()); 

   let writer = fs.createWriteStream('test_copy.txt', {
    flags: 'w'
});
      buf.pipe(writer);

      var util = require('util');

      fs.writeFile('myFile.pdf', util.inspect(logger.requests[requests-1]), (err) => {
        if(!err) console.log('Data written');
      });
```

Actual result: Downloading to download directory
or
Managing to save the file to my desired directory but the file gets corrupted  using FS or FileStream

Desired result: Downloading the file to my desired directory and the PDF doesn't get corrupted

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [downloads-folder](https://github.com/juliangruber/downloads-folder) package, it helps to detect the local Downloads folder.

Comment: This approach wasn't really what I was expecting, since I was working with the Request and trying to give it a path to download.
But, it gave me a new perspective, and it solved the issue, thank you, lets hope the client accepts it